# ビット演算でビットを全部ゼロするときのやり方でどっちが正しいのか知りたい。

Tags: c

ビット演算なのですがビットを全てゼロにする処理を考えていたのですが<<20などをしてビットを
あふれ消す？みたいなことができたんですけどこれは正しい処理の書き方なのでしょうか？
１ビットずつ１になってるビットを消す処理が正しい処理なのですか？

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

void print_bit(unsigned char idx)
{
    unsigned char bit = 1 << 7;
    int i = 0;
    while (bit != 0)
    {
        if (idx & bit)
        {
            printf("1");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("0");
        }

        i++;
        bit >>= 1;
        if (i == 4) {
            printf("_");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

//左に何回シフトするか
unsigned char flag_bit(unsigned char idx,unsigned char p)
{
    unsigned char bit =  1 << 7;
    //unsigned char id = idx;
    if (p == 0)
    {
        p = 1;
    }
    p = 7 - p;

    idx <<= p;
    idx = idx  | bit;
    idx >>= p;


    return idx;

}

int main()
{
    unsigned char x = 0;
    uchar t = 0;
    uchar bit = 1 << 7;
    t = flag_bit(t,2);
    t = flag_bit(t,4);
    print_bit(t);

    t <<= 20;
    print_bit(t);


    getchar();
}
```

Comment: 「ビットをクリアにする処理」とは具体的にはどういう処理でしょうか？　単にすべてのビットを 0 にする処理とは違いますか？

Comment: 全てのビットを `0` にするだけなら `n=0;` で済む話で、真にしたいことは別の内容だと思います。真にやりたいことを書いていただくほうがよさそうっす。

Comment: 昔、なんかの理由で、こんな事やってクリアしてたような記憶が。。。`a ^= a;`なんだったかな？組み込み系とかでのアセンブラの話だったかな？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ビットを消すってこういう事？

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define BITSIZ (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)

static int bitClear(int num, size_t pos)
{
    if (pos >= BITSIZ) {
        return 0;
    }
    //
    int msk = ~(1 << pos);
    //
    return num & msk;
}
//
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", bitClear(0xff, 4));
    //
    return 0;
}
```

usr ~/Project/test % ./a.out
239
usr ~/Project/test %

Answer (score 9):

[INT34-C. 負のビット数のシフトやオペランドのビット数以上のシフトを行わない](https://www.jpcert.or.jp/sc-rules/c-int34-c.html)で説明されていますが、

> 右オペランドの値が負または格上げされた左オペランドのビット幅以上である時、シフト動作は未定義となる (「[未定義の動作51](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/CC.+Undefined+Behavior#CC.UndefinedBehavior-ub_51)」を参照 )。

Undefined Behavior; 未定義の動作とは、Implementation-Defined Behavior; 処理系定義の動作とは異なり、どのような結果が引き起こされても文句は言えません。

具体的には、Intel x86プロセッサ向けコンパイラーであれば、`SHL`；論理左シフトや`SAL`；算術左シフト命令が生成されることが想定されます。しかし、Intel x86プロセッサの`SHL`命令・`SAL`命令は共に下位5bitしか参照せずにシフトを行います。例えば`x <<= 33` と記述した場合、コンパイラーは`SHL EAX, 33`というコードを生成しますが、Intel x86プロセッサは`x <<= 1`相当の処理しか行わず全部ゼロにはならない、といったこともあり得ます。（実例としてはVisual StudioのDebugビルド）

左シフト演算で故意に溢れさせるのは避けるべきです。

Answer (score 0):

> あふれ消す？みたいなことができたんですけどこれは正しい処理

目的次第です。

> １ビットずつ１になってるビットを消す処理

ビット演算では、普通、こっちの処理では無いかと思います。

それ以上は、何がしたいかによります。